# SPTPlaylistSnapshot tracksForPlayback returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

Trying to get all the track in users playlist, it works in Objective-C demo app but when I try in Swift it returns this:

> `<SPTPlaylistList: 0x7fca22d72460>: 0-0 of 1 items (Function)`

I'm using this code:

```
SPTPlaylistList.playlistsForUserWithSession(session, callback: { (error, object) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                var playlists = object as! SPTListPage
                println(playlists)
                SPTPlaylistSnapshot.playlistWithURI(playlists.items[0].uri, accessToken: session.accessToken, callback: { (error:NSError!, obj) -> Void in
                    var playl = obj as! SPTPlaylistSnapshot
                    println(playl.firstTrackPage.tracksForPlayback)
                })
            }

        })
```

and this is the Objective-C code which is working:

```
[SPTPlaylistList playlistsForUserWithSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
    SPTListPage *aa = object;
    NSLog(@"%@",aa.items);
    [SPTPlaylistSnapshot playlistWithURI:[NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify:user:spotifizr:playlist:3bpGFVfycGnhtcEVb95G98"]
                             accessToken:session.accessToken
                                callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistSnapshot *object) {
                                    NSLog(@"tracks on page 1 = %@", [object.firstTrackPage tracksForPlayback]);

                                }];
}];
```

Not sure why it is returning `(function)` in Swift project instead of all the tracks.

Edit : Tried

```
println(playl.firstTrackPage.tracksForPlayback())
```

but now it returns nil, although I have 50 tracks in the playlist.

Comment: Check if `playlists.items [0] .uri` it is sending properly, change `(error: NSError !, obj)` by something like `(error: NSError !, obj: SPTPlaylistSnapshot)` and finally change this `var play1: SPTPlaylistSnapshot = obj` and comment us.

Comment: @eliasRuizHz didnt work, if you have some spare time you can try this test project i have uploaded https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/377

Answer (score 2):

You need to include one or both of the following in your requested scopes, if they aren't already there:
`SPTAuthPlaylistReadScope` and `SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope` allows access to a user's public and private playlists, respectively.

See the Authentication and Scopes section of https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk

Comment: I had [SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope,SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope] and now added [SPTAuthPlaylistReadScore] but still returns nil on my swift project. not sure why